# How do I get a Class object from a compiled type?

Tags: java, class, compile-time

I'm using Java 6.  I have the following code ...

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T>
{
    ...   
    protected T find(final Serializable id)
    {
        T ret = null;
        if (id != null)
        {
            ret = m_entityManager.find(T, id);
        }   // if
        return ret;
    }
```

There is a compile time error on the "ret = m_entityManager.find(T, id);" line because the first argument to the method is expected to be a java.lang.Class object, however, I don't know how to create one given the "T" compile time reference or even if this is possible at all.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't, in general, due to type erasure. Typically you'd have a constructor accepting a `Class<T>`. I'm sure this is a dupe, but I haven't found the relevant duplicate yet - will keep looking.

Comment: *"because the first argument to the method is expected to be a java.lang.Class object"* `T` wouldn't be a `java.lang.Class` object anyway. You'd want `T.class`, and that won't compile either.

Comment: If you find the duplicate, plesae verify that the solution is for Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the class type from the class signature like this:

```
    public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public AbstractHibernateDAO() {
       this.persistentClass = (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected T find(final Serializable id)
    {
        T ret = null;
        if (id != null)
        {
            ret = m_entityManager.find(persistentClass, id);
        }   // if
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, The ParameterizedType class is a Java 7 construct, no?  I'm using Java 6.

Comment: I'm getting the exception, "Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType" on the line within the constructor.

Comment: Scratch that, my mistake.